# How to convert MongooseSchema to Angular .ts file

Tags: arrays, angular, mongoose-schema, angular12

I have this mongoose.Schema

```
 const Recept = mongoose.model("Recept", new mongoose.Schema({
  receptName: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  unique: true,
  trim: true,           
  maxlength: 200  
},
 ingredient: [
      {
        amount: {type: Number, min: 1, required: true},
        unit: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 2},
        ingredientname: {type: String, required: true, trim: true, maxlength: 200}
      }
],
  })
);
```

for my Angular app i made this food.ts file

```
export food{
id!:number;
receptName!:string;
ingredient!:string[];
cookTime!:string;
}
```

===
My question is:  how can i get this(*) part of the mongoose schema
=== (*)this part

```
{
    amount: {type: Number, min: 1, required: true},
    unit: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 2},
    ingredientname: {type: String, required: true, trim: true, maxlength: 200}
  }
```

=====
into / related to the food.ts   `ingredient!:string[];`?

I just can't figure out how to get the array (amount: type:number, unit: type: string, ingredientname:type:string ) into ingredient[]

Is there somewhere a manual on this subject?
I looked into the Mongoose Documentation, but can't really find it.
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

LS,
I am sorry that I was not able to reply earlier - to clarify the problem.

I found the solution to my problem.
My problem was how to (re)write the mongoose. schema to this food.ts file.
The food.ts file is a model for the data I want to get from the back-end.
In the file food.ts, the ingredient is an array that consists of 3 objects: amount/unit/ingredient name.

So i came up with this solution for my food.ts file:

```
export food{
id!:number;
receptName!:string;
ingredient!:{amount:number, unit: string, ingredientname: string}[];
cookTime!:string;
}
```

It works for me! My problem is solved.